# smartcard + configfile: how to avoid error "File name too long"?

Tags: token, pkcs#11, openconnect

I am trying to change my openconnect usage from command line to configfile.
I need to use a smartcard (StarSign CUT S, from Giesecke & Devrient GmbH) in order to access my VPN.
My current command line works fine and I can connect to the VPN:

```bash
$ openconnect \
--authgroup=<my_gateway> \
--protocol=gp \
--servercert <...> \
--disable-ipv6 \
--cafile <file.pem> \
<my_server_url> \
-c "pkcs11:model=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;manufacturer=A.E.T.%20Europe%20B.V.;serial=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;token=XXXXXXXXX;id=<...>;object=<...>;type=cert"
```

But when I try this configfile:
(All arguments are exactly the same!)

```bash
# vpn.config
authgroup = <my_gateway>
protocol = gp
servercert = <...>
disable-ipv6
cafile = <file.pem>
server = <my_server_url>
certificate = "pkcs11:model=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;manufacturer=A.E.T.%20Europe%20B.V.;serial=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;token=XXXXXXXXX;id=<...>;object=<...>;type=cert"
```

I get this error:

```bash
$ openconnect --config=vpn.config
Failed to open key/certificate file <...>: File name too long
Loading certificate failed. Aborting.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to <...>
Failed to complete authentication
```

Any idea on how to make it work? Or is it a bug in openconnect?

Thanks.

PS 1:

```bash
$ openconnect --version
OpenConnect version v9.01
Using GnuTLS 3.7.7. Features present: PKCS#11, HOTP software token, TOTP software token, System keys, DTLS, ESP
Supported protocols: anyconnect (default), nc, gp, pulse, f5, fortinet, array
Default vpnc-script (override with --script): /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script
```

PS 2: All commands executed as root.

Comment: Does removing the quotes (") in the config file work?

Comment: Oh man! It works without double quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes from the configuration file:

```
# vpn.config
...
certificate = pkcs11:model=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;manufacturer=A.E.T.%20Europe%20B.V.;serial=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;token=XXXXXXXXX;id=<...>;object=<...>;type=cert
```